# Renaming XML nodes using E4X in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I have an XML object in AS3 that is formatted as follows:

```
<data>
  <nodes>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    ...
  </nodes>
  <nodes>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    ...
  </nodes>
  ...
</data>
```

My problem is I want to rename the node names("nodes" and "item") to something more relevant e.g. "*nodes*" could be "*author*", and "*item*" could be "*book*".

So what would be the best way to do this with E4X in AS3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the `setName()` method of XML Object in AS3.

example:

```
   //extract all nodes named "nodes"

    var l:XMLList=data..nodes;
    for each(var n:XML in l){
       n.setName("new_node_name");
    }

    //extract all nodes named "item"

    var l2:XMLList=data..item;
    for each(var n2:XML in l2){
       n2.setName("new_item_name");
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be something like:
    data..nodes.setName("new_node_name");
But that would be asking too much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this natively within ActionScript, however here is a simple function that will accomplish just that. First I am converting it to a string, then using a simple regular expression to find and replace all instances.

```
function replaceAll(findTag:String, replaceWith:String, source:XML):XML
    {
        var xmls:String = source.toXMLString();
        var findPattern:RegExp = new RegExp(findTag, "g");
        xmls = xmls.replace(findPattern, replaceWith);
        return new XML(xmls);
    }
```

Hope it helps.